# Abrir arquivos da máquina local via Javascript

Tags: javascript, arquivo

Eu preciso simplesmente executar um arquivo local via Javascript.

Por exemplo, no `C#` eu tenho o `System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("C:\\teste.txt")` que vai abrir no bloco de notas o `teste.txt`.

Como faço para abrir `teste.txt`  em Javascript?

Comment: A partir de um browser? Não dá, tem restrição de segurança. Imagine se um site qualquer conseguisse rodar um executável qualquer na sua máquina...